# Use google sheets to grab some values

Tags: google-sheets

Based on some searches I tried some syntaxes, but it didn't work. I want to grab the averagehashrate

https://api.ethermine.org/miner/0x819135fe6fe2c8a3fa1348a9fa70fee3764a966b/worker/10/currentStats

please help me

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A25)); 
 "where Col1 contains 'averageHashrate'"); "\d+(?:.\d+)?")
```

[image]